# How can I get my GUI Degree Converter to work properly?

Tags: java, user-interface

What I am trying to do is make it so that the value I enter in the text fields can be interacted with, but it always involves me trying to convert from String to double. I am a HS freshman in Comp Sci I, and this is pretty frustrating because I put a lot of thought in this. Give this a look, please:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class degConverter extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JLabel welcome;
    private JTextField f, c;
    private JButton fI, cI;
    private JButton reset, convertF, convertC;

    public degConverter() {
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.red.darker());

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Celsius-Fahrenheit/Fahrenheit-Celsius Converter.");
        setSize(900, 750);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocation(500, 200);

        welcome = new JLabel("Welcome to the amazing degree converter!");
        welcome.setBounds(320, 50, 300, 40);
        contentPane.add(welcome);

        fI = new JButton("Convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius");
        fI.setBounds(100, 150, 275, 40);
        fI.addActionListener(this);
        contentPane.add(fI);

        cI = new JButton("Convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit");
        cI.setBounds(525, 150, 275, 40);
        cI.addActionListener(this);
        contentPane.add(cI);

        f = new JTextField("Give me a value here");
        f.addActionListener(this);
        contentPane.add(f);

        c = new JTextField("Give me a value here");
        c.addActionListener(this);
        contentPane.add(c);

        reset = new JButton("RESET DIS MOFUCKIN SHIT");
        reset.setBounds(325, 550, 220, 40);
        reset.addActionListener(this);
        contentPane.add(reset);

        convertF = new JButton("CONVERT!!!");
        convertF.addActionListener(this);
        contentPane.add(convertF);

        convertC = new JButton("CONVERT!!!");
        convertC.addActionListener(this);
        contentPane.add(convertC);

        String s = c.getText();
        double cIn = Double.parseDouble(s);
        double fOut = ((1.8) * (cIn)) + 32;
        String s2 = f.getText();
        double fIn = Double.parseDouble(s2);
        double cOut = ((fIn - 32) / 1.8);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        degConverter frame = new degConverter();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
            JButton clicked = (JButton) e.getSource();
            {
                if (fI == clicked) {
                    fI.setText("Insert value in box below");
                    f.setBounds(100, 275, 250, 40);
                    convertF.setBounds(100, 400, 150, 40);
                }
            }
            if (e.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
                if (cI == clicked) {
                    cI.setText("Insert value in the box below");
                    c.setBounds(525, 275, 250, 40);
                    convertC.setBounds(525, 400, 150, 40);
                }
            }
            if (reset == clicked) {
                fI.setText("Convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius");
                cI.setText("Convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit");
                f.setBounds(1000, 1000, 0, 0);
                c.setBounds(1000, 1000, 0, 0);
            }
            if (convertF == clicked) {
                f.setText(cOut);
            }
            if (convertC == clicked) {
                f.setText(fOut);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do here seems to not be working. Help? Thanks in advance. Sorry for the long program.

Comment: Try to reduce your code to the smallest example that displays the problem. And change the caption on your button...

Comment: `null` layouts are not your friend

Comment: don't put all of your code in one action listener. Either create an `ActionListener` or `Action` instance for each of your components and put the respective code in each instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code

```
  String s = c.getText();
    double cIn = Double.parseDouble(s);
    double fOut = ((1.8)*(cIn))+32;
    String s2 = f.getText();
    double fIn = Double.parseDouble(s2);
    double cOut = ((fIn-32)/1.8);
```

Gets called before the user had time to enter anything. You need to change things so that pressing the "convert" button calls this code - and only the first bit (c to f) if initial value is c, and only the second bit (f to c) if initial value is Fahrenheit.

Comment: yes, there's a difference between `actionPerformed()` and the `degConverter` constructor